# Project isn't linked with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run [google firebase example](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) but got an "Project isn't linked with Gradle" error when opens gradle file. Also files visible only in "project-veiw". It looks it because projet use gradle.kts. How i need to set it up to make project working?

[image]

Comment: How did you open the project?

Comment: Remove .kts extension from gradle files and import project selecting build.gradle

Comment: Oh guys. That's using Kotlin-dsl. Check this link: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/tree/master/doc/getting-started

Comment: @yole, downloafing zip, extract, open from android studio.

Comment: @Héctor not helped, kts gradle uses it's own syntax.

Comment: @Mohsen, thank you. i'll try

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had similar issue.

I have Added empty build.gradle file in the root of the project that uses Gradle Kotlin DSL (projects may use build.gradle.kts for config, however empty build.gradle file is required by grade to function correctly)

**Update:**

You should also add this line to `settings.gradle.kts` file:

`rootProject.buildFileName = "build.gradle.kts"`

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer -- see the one below by Vitaly Chirkov

Answer (score 42):

Right click on `build.gradle.kts` > `Import Gradle project` should help.
No need to add empty `build.gradle` nor set `rootProject.buildFileName`.

Comment: This will only work, for a single computer right? Every dev that will check out the project will have to do it?

Comment: @IgorWojda still seems better than have extra file and extra root project setting.

Comment: @VitalyChirkov This depends on the scenario - for a single dev we could argue that it is indeed a better solution, however, in general, our goal is to have a project that requires a minimal amount of configuration after opening/importing (ideally zero - just open the project and everything works). This is even more crucial for the bigger teams were project complexity is often higher and newly joined devs can import projects easier without performing additional (and redundant) configuration tasks.

Comment: @IgorWojda, yeh, but I think that correct implementation of Kotlin DSL project import is just a matter of time.

Comment: @VitalyChirkov This depends on the scenario - for a single dev we could argue that it is indeed a better solution, however, in general, our goal is to have a project that requires a minimal amount of configuration after opening/importing (ideally zero - just open the project and everything works). This is even more crucial for the bigger teams were project complexity is often higher and newly joined devs can import projects easier without performing additional (and redundant) configuration tasks.

Comment: I've had a similar problem and sharing the file `.idea/gradle.xml` solved the problem for me (I'm talking about the team sharing scenario where you want everything to work once a new member clones the project)